# Getting byte type object in prediction

Tags: machine-learning, prediction, amazon-sagemaker, endpoint

I am getting Byte type value returned from predict function on a data.

```
from sagemaker.predictor import Predictor
from sagemaker.serializers import CSVSerializer
from sagemaker.deserializers import JSONDeserializer

predictor1 = Predictor(endpoint_name=predictor.endpoint_name, serializer=CSVSerializer(), deserializers = CSVDeserializer())

result = predictor1.predict(data)
print(type(result))
print(result)
```

<class 'bytes'>
b'{"probabilities": [[0.9999768137931824, 2.3188162231235765e-05]]}'

Comment: Is there a way so that model do not return Byte in prediction. I know I can use decode('utf-8') on value returned to make it dictionary object but how to make it return a non-byte value

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using the predict method, the output is passed in bytes. But there is no sagemaker function you have to use to solve the problem.

Just use [decode()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode) and [eval()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=eval#eval) to retrieve the parameters correctly:

```py
decoded_string = result.decode('utf-8')
json_from_string = eval(decoded_string)
print(json_from_string['probabilities'][0])
```

output will be:

```
[0.9999768137931824, 2.3188162231235765e-05]
```